# i am trying to rate user but user only able to rate himself

Tags: laravel

[image: Inside my rating table where user_id=2 is the id who is giving the review]There are two users in my users table user1 and user2
the user2 wants to rate user1
i have created a Rating table 
which is as

```
 Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('rating')->nullable();
            $table->string('review')->nullable();
            $table->integer('rated_user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

i have also created a model named Rating and defined a realtionship to the user
such as

```
public function user()
{
    return$this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

the code in my user model is as follow

```
 public function Rating()
      {
          return $this->hasOne(Rating::class);
      }
```

the code inside Ratingcontroller store function is as follow

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $rating = new Rating;
        $rating->fill($request->all());
        $rating->user_id = Auth::id();
        $rating->save();
       return redirect()->back();
    }
```

the problem is that in the rating table 
every things looks fine 
user_id is getting the id who is trying to post comment 
and rated_user_id is givving the id to which the user is giving rating too 
but the user is only able to rate himself not other users ..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212305/discussion-on-question-by-zaeem-syed-i-am-trying-to-rate-user-but-user-only-able).

Answer (score 0):

The image in db is correct and Your `store` method in `RatingsController` is also works as expected.

So You want from us to give You code example to `ProfileController` method to get ratings provided by user and provided to user.

1) You've to add to **User** model following relation:

```
public function ratingsProvidedByMe() 
{
  return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function ratingsProvidedToMe()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, 'rated_user_id', 'id')
}
```

2) in **Rating** model:

```
public function ratedBy()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function ratedTo()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'rated_user_id');
}
```

3) in Your **ProfileController**:

```
public function view(Request $request) 
{
  $ratingsProvidedByMe = 
    Rating::with('ratedTo')
             ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
             ->all();
  $ratingsProvidedToMe = 
    Rating::with('ratedBy')
             ->where('rated_user_id', Auth::id())
             ->all();

  $me = $user = Auth::user();

  return view(
    'profiles.view', 
    compact(
      'ratingsProvidedByMe', 
      'ratingsProvidedToMe', 
      'user', 'me'
    )
  );
}
```

P.S. it's just an example, adapt my example to Your project Yourself.